# To show that a complex-valued function is injective

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given a complex-valued function $w=f(z) = - \dfrac{1}{2} \left( z + \dfrac{1}{z} \right)$ from $\{ z= x+iy : |z| < 1 \}$ to $\{ w : \text{Im}(w) >0 \}$, show that $f$ is injective.

**My Approach :** Let $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$ which yields
$$(z_1-z_2) + \left( \frac{\overline{z_1}}{|z_1|^2} - \frac{\overline{z_2}}{|z_2|^2} \right) = 0 .$$
From here how can I conclude that $z_1 = z_2$ ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to define $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks ! I just did.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f$ is defined only on $\{z: 0<|z|<1\}$. It is not defined at $0$.

You have $z_1-z_2+(\frac 1 {z_1}-\frac  1{z_2})=0$. This can be written as $\frac 1  {z_1z_2} (1-z_1z_2)(z_1-z_2)=0$. Since $|z_1z_2| <1$ it follows that $1-z_1z_2 \neq 0$. Hence, $z_1=z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Alt. hint: $\;f(z)=w \iff z^2 + 2w z+ 1 = 0\,$. The quadratic has two roots whose product is $1$, so only one of them can be inside the unit circle $|z| \lt 1$.